# Rails link_to not loading leaflet map

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, leaflet

I've come across a really strange (at least to me) issue.  When I type the url by hand the map load just fine, however, when I use a link (either rails or a href) the map won't load until I hit refresh.

Any ideas?

**`routes.rb`**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'page#map'
end
```

**`application.html.erb`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LeafletTest</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**`map.html.erb`**

```
<%= link_to("reload page (rails)", root_path) %><br />
<a href="\">reload page (a href)</a><br />

<div id="mapid"></>
```

**`page.scss`**

```
#mapid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

**`page.coffee`**

```
$ ->
  map = L.map('mapid').setView([
    51.505
    -0.09
  ], 13)
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors').addTo map
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by ensuring a new TileLayer was created every time the map was rendered, i.e. when `turbolinks:load` is fired.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of some other posts, I finally discovered that this was due to Turbolinks, and the way it calls a page load.  Adding the `data: { turbolinks: false}` attribute to my rails link helped clear it up.  I imagine it would work (with the correct formatting) for a non-rails link.